# Error when transferring Plex watch history from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: plex, sqlite, sqlite3

I have been running a Plex server on a Windows PC, and want to move over to an Ubuntu PC.

I'm trying to do this by just fresh installing Plex and moving over the watch history.

I followed the instructions from Plex to export the data here:
https://support.plex.tv/articles/201154527-move-viewstate-ratings-from-one-install-to-another/

I have the settings.sql file, but am having trouble importing it to my new Plex instance in Ubuntu.

When I execute the command:

```
cat settings.sql | sqlite3 com.plexapp.plugins.library.db
```

I get this error:

```
Error: near line 1: in prepare, near "��P": syntax error (1)
```

And here's a screenshot in case I made a typo:
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKTmZ.png)

I'm lost on where to look or what to try next, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you ask this on the Plex support forum as it has many entries on this.